# Social websites API for .NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, linkedin-api

I wanted to integrate social websites using their API. Is there any free API which ease this work? Like Facebook, [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) and Google.

My intention is to give the user the opportunity to login/register through these websites to
get profile information specially from LinkedIn and Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Facebook SDK. There is a [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) which will get you started quickly:

- [Documentation](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/)
- [Source code](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a great API for that and [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/), and you can [download the Facebook API](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/39727) if you need it.